# php request authorization from remote server

Tags: php, json, authentication

I have two servers, server 1 (the host) is provide content to server 2 (the client).

On server 2 I am using

```
file_get_contents('http://domain1.com/shared/portal.php?file=testfile');
```

to retrieve the requested file content. But before this content can be retrieved on server 2 I would like to implement some sort of authentication (username/password). I was thinking about including a username and password query in the url for fgc and checking the db on server 1 before the content is sent back but there will be some cases where the fgc content will need to be printed multiple times through a loop so if the fgc is called say 10 times I don't want to hit the db on server 1 10 times.

So basically I would like to be able to make one call to an auth file on server one or something similar that will give access to the content fetched by the fgc. Maybe with JSON or something? But I've never used JSON with php so I'm not sure how that would work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Update to be more sepecific apparently**: I would like some pointers on some methods I could use that would give server 2 the authorization to retreive the requested file from server 1. If authorization is not granted through username/password or access key then the content of the file requested with fgc would return empty or denial message.

So right now my setup is like this on each server, I would like to perform an authorization attempt before the fgc content is retrieved if possible.

```
(Server 1 Portal.php)

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://domain1.com/shared/css/style.css">
<?php
$fileName = $_GET["file"];

/* allow authorization through access key or username/password in this file or separate file preferably */

if ($fileName) {
   include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/shared/content/".$fileName.".php");
} else {
   echo "Missing file name.";   
}
?>

<script src="http://domain1.com/shared/js/functions.js"></script>
```

Then on server 2 I have something like this

```
(Server 2 index.php)
<?php
/* request authorization from server 1 to ensure content is allowed to be sent */
// once authorization completes get content from server 1
$test = file_get_contents('http://domain1.com/shared/portal.php?file=testfile');
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
   <?php echo $test; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I thought my op was pretty to the point.. I want to request authorization from server 1 on server 2 before server is able to get the contents of the fgc from server 1. @absalon.valdes

Comment: thanks for the down vote whoever did that.

Comment: @bugfixer I'm aware that I need to create access keys.. I mentioned that in my op. I was asking for pointers on how to go about doing such a thing.. Thanks for your brilliant input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `stream_context_create` (or CURL) to make a request. But server 1 **must implement** the authentication process to allow downloads from server 2.

```
<?php                                                                              

$context = stream_context_create(array(                                            
    'http'   => array(                                                             
        'method' => 'GET',                                                             
        'header' => sprintf('Authorization: Basic %s', base64_encode('username:password'))
    )
));                                                                                

$fileUrl  = 'http://domain1.com/shared/portal.php?file=testfile'                                                                                                                                         
$contents = file_get_contents($fileUrl, false, $context);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer/suggestion. I haven't ever had to do something like this with php before so I'm having a bit of trouble getting my head around the whole thing. Sorry for my ignorance but im assuming the second parameter in the fgc is cache correct? And obviously the 3rd param is a header sent to the file before its retrieval right? In portal.php on server 1 am going to read the values of the header and decode them then use that info to ping the database?

Comment: Also do you think it would be possible to submit one request before that could effect the output of the retrieved file? In some cases the same file will be called on multiple times and I feel like hitting the db multiple times in one page load can effect load speeds. I know that I can't pass session values correct? Maybe I could do a separate fgc first which would return a pass or fail string and pass that in as my header on the fgc for the actual content then just check for a pass or fail header on portal.php? Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: The second parameter tells php if should look for the file in the include path. HTTP protocol is stateless. You shouldn't depend on a first request to make a second one. If the http authentication fails just return an error 500 or something like that.

Comment: Ok I'll consider your advice.. The only reason I want to make a auth request first is so I dont have to hit the database several times during a loop on server 2

Comment: In that case you should consider a more advanced authentication system, eg cookies or php session handling.

Comment: I can't pass sessions to the second server though right? I have considered cookies as well.. I will play with both ideas and see how it goes. Thank you for you help